# How can I get adwords user's account info?

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-ads-api

I want that every users can get their google adwords campaign data from our site.
So in first step, I generated authorization url with user's id from google api.
And then, I got code from google and generate access_token, stored refresh_token in db per user.
And in second step, I created AdwordsSession from refresh_token, and tried to use this session to get each user's campaign datas.
But in this case, I got permission_denied errors.
How can I solve this?

The code of generating authorization url is below

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Auth\CredentialsLoader;
use Google\Auth\OAuth2;

require_once('../credintal.php');

$callbackUrl = "http://networks.ezond.com/adwords/callback.php";
$scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me";
$AUTHORIZATION_URI = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth';

$oauth2 = new OAuth2([
        'authorizationUri' => $AUTHORIZATION_URI,
        'redirectUri' => $callbackUrl,
        'tokenCredentialUri' => CredentialsLoader::TOKEN_CREDENTIAL_URI,
        'clientId' => $googleClientID,
        'clientSecret' => $googleClientSecret,
        'scope' => $scopes,
        'state' => $userID
    ]);

$authUrl = $oauth2->buildFullAuthorizationUri();
```

And then, the code snippet to get data from auth url is below.

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Auth\CredentialsLoader;
use Google\Auth\OAuth2;

use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsServices;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSession;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSessionBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\ReportSettings;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\ReportSettingsBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\Reporting\v201705\DownloadFormat;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\Reporting\v201705\ReportDefinition;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\Reporting\v201705\ReportDefinitionDateRangeType;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\Reporting\v201705\ReportDownloader;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\ApiException;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\Paging;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\Predicate;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\PredicateOperator;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\ReportDefinitionReportType;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\Selector;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\OrderBy;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\SortOrder;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\mcm\ManagedCustomerService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\mcm\CustomerService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\ReportDefinitionService;

require_once('../credintal.php');

    $userID = $_GET["state"];
    $userAgent = $googleAppName;

    $callbackUrl = "http://networks.ezond.com/adwords/callback.php";
    $scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me";
    $AUTHORIZATION_URI = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth';

    $oauth2 = new OAuth2([
        'authorizationUri' => $AUTHORIZATION_URI,
        'redirectUri' => $callbackUrl,
        'tokenCredentialUri' => CredentialsLoader::TOKEN_CREDENTIAL_URI,
        'clientId' => $googleClientID,
        'clientSecret' => $googleClientSecret,
        'scope' => $scopes,
        'approval_prompt' => "force"
    ]);


    $oauth2->setCode($code);
    $authToken = $oauth2->fetchAuthToken();

    $session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
        ->fromFile()
        ->withOAuth2Credential($oauth2)
        ->build();

    $adWordsServices = new AdWordsServices();

    $customerService = $adWordsServices->get($session, CustomerService::class);
    $page = $customerService->getCustomers();
    echo ($page[0]->getCanManageClients());
```

In this case, I can get auth url, code and token, session successfully, bu can't get data from next step.
The code snippet of the error generated is below.

```
$customerService = $adWordsServices->get($session, CustomerService::class);
$page = $customerService->getCustomers();
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error message with a stack trace? `CustomerService.getCustomers()` should never give a `USER_PERMISSION_DENIED` error.

Comment: I thought such like that, too. But if I comment that line, then no errors.

Comment: I uploaded video screenshot file on server. The url is [link]https://networks.ezond.com/test.mp4

Comment: `#0 /ezond/networks/adwords/vendor/googleads/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/AdsApi/Common/Util/Reflection.php(39): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)

`

Comment: `#1 /ezond/networks/adwords/vendor/googleads/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/AdsApi/Common/AdsSoapClient.php(162): Google\AdsApi\Common\Util\Reflection->createInstance('Google\\AdsApi\\A...', Array)`

Comment: error log is too long to upload within comment.

Comment: `#2 /ezond/networks/adwords/vendor/googleads/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/AdsApi/Common/AdsSoapClient.php(126): Google\AdsApi\Common\AdsSoapClient->parseApiExceptionFromSoapFault(Object(SoapFault))`

Comment: `#3 /ezond/networks/adwords/vendor/googleads/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/AdsApi/AdWords/v201705/mcm/CustomerService.php(92): Google\AdsApi\Common\AdsSoapClient->__soapCall('getCustomers', Array)
`

Comment: `2017/07/24 10:58:44 [error] 13936#0: *468 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\ApiException: [AuthorizationError.USER_PERMISSION_DENIED @ ; trigger:'<null>'] in /ezond/networks/adwords/vendor/googleads/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/AdsApi/Common/Util/Reflection.php:39`